# Redirect to page list when page published

Tags: pages, publish

I have a role that allows users to self publish pages but does not allow them to delete or edit after. 
Currently, when a page is published it returns the restricted 'Cheating' message as the user cannot view the page in edit view.

Please can someone tell me how it is possible for the publish action to redirect the user back to the page list rather than the edit view?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the below code which works as expected if anyone else is looking for similar.

```
add_action( 'publish_page', 'redirect_user_page_list', 10, 3 );
function redirect_user_page_list() {
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $role = ( array ) $user->roles;
        if ( 'role_slug' == $role[0] ) {
            $url = 'url to redirect to';
            wp_redirect($url);
           exit;
        }
    }
}
```